# HTML link within my plugin settings page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, urls, links

My plugin has a settings page. It's working fine. Now, i want to put a html link within this page. This link will go to another settings page. How could I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just use old simple HTML, the `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="admin.php?page=yourplugin/another-page.php" title="another page">Another Page</a>
```

If your page is php only:

```
echo '<a href="admin.php?page=yourplugin/another-page.php" title="another page">Another Page</a>';
```

Where `yourplugin` is your plugin folder name, and `another-page.php` is that other page.

Comment: But I don't want to leave wordpress... i want to stay there... It's just another settings page. Thanks.

Comment: You can use relative urls, the fact that you use html doesn't mean you're leaving wordpress, you could use: `<a href="themes.php?page=another_page">Another page</a>` and that'll take you to `http://yoursite/wordpress/wp-admin/themes.php?page=another_page` I'll update my answer